# C# Simple Event Handler for Setting Alarm

Tags: c#, visual-studio, events, event-handling

Why does the following line "alarm.AlarmEvent += new AlarmEventHandler(alarm_Sound);" gives me "An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'AlarmClock.Alarm.alarm_Sound(object, System.EventArgs)'"

```
   public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Alarm alarm = new Alarm(new DateTime(2010, 4, 7, 23, 2, 0));
        alarm.Set();
        alarm.AlarmEvent += new AlarmEventHandler(alarm_Sound);            
    }
```

Full source code here:
[Program.cs](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/4256111/Program.cs)
[AlarmEventArgs](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/4256111/AlarmEventArgs.cs)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're adding the event handler after calling the `Set` method.
Therefore, when the `Set` method raises the event, it doesn't have a handler yet.

Answer (score 4):

Your `alarm_Sound` method is an instance method, meaning that it can only be used on an *instance* of your class.
Since `Main` is a `static` method, it is not associated with an instance of the class, so you cannot use any instance methods in it.

You need to make your `alarm_Sound` handler method a static method by adding the `static` keyword to its declaration.

Alternatively, you could create an instance of the class, then reference the handler method of that instance.

Comment: I thought by doing "Alarm alarm = new Alarm(new DateTime(2010, 4, 7, 23, 2, 0));" I have already created an instance?

Comment: @yeeen: Then you need to use that instance by adding `alarm.alarm_Sound`.

Comment: Can compile alr. But, it doesn't work. It prints out "hey!" from my AlarmEventArgs constructor and continues looping. The event alarm_Sound doesn't get invoked (no "Ring ring ring!"), how come?

Answer (score 0):

Because the alarm_Sound method is defined in the context of the Class named Alarm in the Program.cs file, so, for calling it, you would need a instance of that class.

It would be better to define it as `static` so you don't need an instance for calling that method