# Alarm class in C#

Tags: c#, alarm

Is there a pre-defined Alarm class in C#?

I was reading [C# Simple Event Handler for Setting Alarm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2593988/c-simple-event-handler-for-setting-alarm) and can't figure out how if it exists.

Comment: No.<!---------------------------->

Comment: What do you want this alarm class to do?

Comment: The Alarm class from the mentioned post is not a standard .NET class.

Comment: There is no `Alarm` class. That example was showing a custom made `Alarm` class.

Comment: That's a class that he wrote.

Comment: The easiest way to find out if something exists in the .NET Framework is to search at msdn.com. If you don't see a class description in the first page of entries, you can bet it's not in the .NET Framework. And no, it doesn't appear to be there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no pre-defined `Alarm` class in C#.

However, you can find it in this msdn article: [Raising an Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wkzf914z%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)

Comment: Wow, that `Alarm` class is a travesty. How was that ever printed?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`System.Threading.Timer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer.aspx). There are other [timers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164015.aspx) too, but `System.Threading.Timer` is a good place to start to mimic alarm functionality in .NET.

Answer (score 2):

There is an Alarm class in the Windows Phone OS 7.1 development platform, however, in the case of the code that you were reading, he was using a custom class.

Docs about  Microsoft.Phone.Scheduler.Alarm
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.scheduler.alarm(v=vs.92).aspx

If in the future you're looking for a class, trying searching for the class name on msdn.com, there is pretty good documentation about most classes in .net.